# Should you GET or PUT

Tags: spring, rest

I am learning Spring and writing a API.
I have a function that will change isActive field in database from true to false.
I am hesitant about "What kind of HTTP methods should use?"

Comment: Use PUT method. It should contain a payload to modify data and in return, the modified data.

Comment: Thank you, my request doesn't have payload, can i use get ?

Answer (score 0):

`PUT`.

From RESTful we know HTTP method is mapping the corresponding operation in sql.

- `GET` == `read`
- `PUT` == `update` (or `create` if the client can determine the resource uri)
- `POST` == `create`
- `DELETE` == `delete`

Comment: Yes, i know it. But my request doesn't have payload. Is it oke if i use get ?

Comment: @emulatalk1. No, if your request has a side-effect it must not be GET.